# Resizing a parent div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, resize

I'm trying to set up a page where when the user clicks on one of the letters within the 3 divs, that div resizes and "covers" up the other two divs on the screen - but I hit a brick wall with the jquery statement - I know it involves the resize function (and probably the css function) but I can't figure out for the life of me how exactly to do it.

HTML/CSS

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="home" class="group">   <span class="lettering" id="A">
            A
            </span>

    </div>
    <div id="portfolio" class="group" style="margin-left: -4px;">   <span class="lettering" id="P">
            P
            </span>

    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="group" style="margin-left: -4px;"> <span class="lettering" id="C">
            C
            </span>

    </div>
</div>

html, body {
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#home {
    background-color: #4D90FE;
}
.group {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#portfolio {
    background-color: #DD4B39;
}
#contact {
    background-color: #777777;
}
.lettering {
    color: #fff;
    font: bolder 7em'Bitter Bold';
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    /*------------------------
    Set Divs to 1/3 Width of Screen
    ------------------------*/
    $(".group").css("width", ($(window).width() * 1 / 3));
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(".group").css('height', $(window).height());
        $(".group").css("width", ($(window).width() * 1 / 3));
    });
    /*------------------------
    Vertically Center Div
    ------------------------*/
    $('.lettering').css("top", ($('.group').height() - $('.lettering').height()) / 2);
    /*-----------------------
    Expand Div on Element Click
    -----------------------*/
    $('.lettering').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().resize(function () {
            /* ??? */
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qg8Zd/

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position all divs absolute, and change the div of that which hath been clicked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".group").each(function(index, element)
    {
        var len = $(".group").length;
        //console.log((100 / len * index) + "%");
        $(element).css("left", (100 / len * index) + "%");
    });

    $('.lettering').click(function ()
    {
        $(this).parent().animate({ width: "100%", left: 0 }, 500).css("z-index", 1);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qg8Zd/5/)

[Resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) is not what you think, it is an event fired when the window element size changes by the user.

/edited to accommodate changes
/edited again for animation

Comment: This doesn't animate, and the expanding div doesn't cover up the others. It just pushes them down.

Comment: Works like a charm, is there a way to make the animation more fluid instead of it just "appearing" at full width?

Comment: @TaiM. http://jsfiddle.net/WL3ZA/. Did you actually want the others to be pushed down instead of being covered up?

Comment: @Asad I figured I could wiggle my way around that inconsistency (I noticed that they were pushed down as well) but if they were to be covered up, it would make the rest of the page easier to deal with

Comment: @TaiM. Yeah the divs being pushed down was an overlook, simply fixed that with display: none. Although he never mentioned it being animated

Comment: @TaiM. Sorry, linked to the wrong fiddle. [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/WL3ZA/) is animated.

Comment: @Asad That second fiddle works fine, I figured setting the z-index of the affected div to a number above 1 would simply allow it to "cover" up the other two divs, I'm not sure if it works in practice, but I'm sure I can figure it out

Comment: @TaiM. updated the fiddle, took me longer than it should have. Fiddle with the CSS though, gave the container relative positioning to be able to position the 3 divs absolute.